# I am getting error when I build the application in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies

Hello Everyone I am getting error when I build the apk in flutter project. I am not sure whether its is because of code or some setup issue. I think that there is something wrong in setupping flutter.

The error states that:

```
PS F:\FYP\Code\Recipedia> flutter build apk --build-name Recipedia --build-number 01

Building with sound null safety

w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in 
the classpath:
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 
1.5)
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 
1.6)
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin- 
stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 
1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing 
them from the classpath
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in 
the classpath:
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 
1.5)
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 
1.6)
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin- 
stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
C:/Users/safin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib- 
common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 
1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing 
them from the classpath
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          772.7s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (22.3MB).
```

This is the output of `flutter run --verbose`

```
PS F:\FYP\Code\Recipedia> flutter run --verbose
[  +91 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +163 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +2 ms] e99c9c7cd9f6c0b2f8ae6e3ebfd585239f5568f4
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git tag --points-at         
e99c9c7cd9f6c0b2f8ae6e3ebfd585239f5568f4
[ +100 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at e99c9c7cd9f6c0b2f8ae6e3ebfd585239f5568f4
[   +1 ms] 3.3.7
[  +95 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{upstream}
[  +85 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{upstream}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +88 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +147 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +89 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +159 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping 
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping 
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +10 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +120 ms] executing: C:\Users\safin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices 
-l
[ +166 ms] List of devices attached
[  +27 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping 
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping 
update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +23 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +128 ms] No supported devices connected.
[  +45 ms] The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:
       Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 
10.0.19045.2193]
       Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.88
       Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.26
       If you would like your app to run on web or windows, consider running `flutter create 
.` to generate projects for these  
platforms.

[  +22 ms] "flutter run" took 606ms.
[  +37 ms]
       #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
       #1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:491:7)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand             
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1330:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>         
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand 
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
       <asynchronous suspension>


[  +42 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 32ms
[   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Please help me to resolve the isssue so I can build the apk without any errors. Thankyou :)

Comment: Maybe this post answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69653870/flutter-error-some-runtime-jar-files-in-the-classpath-have-an-incompatible-ve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem so I tried running `flutter upgrade` and worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).